# firebase firestore did they change the return promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

from today 26/10/2020 i get back other data after i do a database call to collection.
this is abreaking change for me i have to change my total code this is days work.
userName variable before today was all ways working
when is delete userName my code works then i get to other page
and the code is broken again
error

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined

my code

```
 handleLogin = async () => {    
    await fire
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.userName, this.state.password)
      .then((u) => {
        console.log(u)
        this.props.toggleLogin();
        db.collection('users')
          .where('userId', '==', u.user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            let result = res.docs;
            console.log(result)
            let userName =
              result[0]._E.$t.proto.mapValue.fields.userName.stringValue;

            this.props.setUser(u.user.uid, userName);
            sessionStorage.setItem('userId', u.user.uid);
          });
        this.props.history.push('/portfolio');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        if (this.state.email === '') {
          this.dialog.showAlert('Please enter a valid email');
        } else if (this.state.password === '') {
          this.dialog.showAlert('Please enter a valid password');
        }
      });
  };
```

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky i have multiple documents of multiple users. and the docId is somthing that change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to rely on the undocumented, minified internal implementation of the Firestore SDK, which is not at all guaranteed to work.

I think what you want here is:

```
let result = res.docs;
let userName = result[0].get('userName');
```

Comment: So its not good practice to use result[0]._E.$t.proto.mapValue.fields.userName.stringValue; ? its beter to use result[0].get('userName'); ?

Comment: Correct, we only guarantee the behavior of [documented methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore). Stick with things that appear in the reference docs and you'll be in good shape.

Comment: Thanks for the help i still got one question. So the get() will alway give me the same result like  result[0]._E.$t.proto.mapValue.fields.userName.stringValue. in this example then it would be userName